# Searching database to return a number back to javascript using two javascript variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can I set `color` to be a 0, 1, 2 , or a 3 depending if certain things in the database are `null`?

I also need to pass variables back from Javascript to PHP. How can I do that?

```
var date = year + '-' + showM + '-' + showD + ' ' + '00:00:00';
var  eid=0001;
console.log(date);
var color = <?php
    require_once('mcl_Oci.php');
    $xdm = new mcl_Oci("xdm");`
    $sql = "SELECT x.*,x.ROWID FROM test.FORM x 
    WHERE DATE_OF_FORM =Get(Date)
WHERE EID =GET(eid)
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is executed server-side so it's impossible for it to recover the value of the eid variable since it's always executed first. The only way to pass a variable from Javascript to PHP is with an AJAX call. If you have JQuery, you can easily do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path/to/my/script.php",
    data: {EID: eid, DateForm: date},
    type: "POST",
    success: myCallback
});

function myCallback(data)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

EDIT: Here's a general idea of how the PHP should look like:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT x.*,x.ROWID FROM test.FORM x 
                            WHERE DATE_OF_FORM = :dateForm AND EID = :eid");

$stmt->bindValue(":dateForm", $_POST['DateForm']);
$stmt->bindValue(":dateForm", $_POST['EID']);
$stmt->execute();

echo "<rows>";
while($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<row>";
        echo "<field1>" . $res['Field1'] ."</field1>";
        echo "<field2>" . $res['Field2'] ."</field2>";
    echo "</row>";
}
echo "</rows>";
```

Comment: what does the php look like

Comment: I added an example of how the PHP should look like